# Get a value from a HTML form in a Angular 2 ag-grid

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ag-grid

I have a form that appears in a modal in my HTML file and i would like to add the values i get form the form in a ag-grid array, and i have no idea how to do this.

This is my file.html

```
<template #addTrainContent let-c="close" let-d="dismiss">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Ajouter un train</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="d('Cross click')">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="radio" name="choiceDirection" /> Gauche
        <input type="radio" name="choiceDirection" /> Droite

        <input type="number" placeholder="Numéro de matériel"   value="nMateriel"/>
        <select>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>52</option>
            <option>38</option>
        </select>

        <input type="checkbox" checked /> Créer dans l'ATS
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" (click)="c(createTrain())">Ajouter le train</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" (click)="c('Close click')">Annuler</button>
    </div>

</template>
```

And i was adding a train with value i chose instead of the ones from the form, like that in my file.ts

```
createNewTrain() {
    var newTrain = {
        nMateriel: 97,
        nRame: 42,
        position: 'TB__BLOC_13',
        direction: 'droite',
        etat: 'mouvement',
        vitesse: '24 km/h'
    };

    return newTrain;
}

createTrain() {
    var newItem = this.createNewTrain();
    this.gridOptions.api.addItems( [newItem] );
    this.rowCount++;
}
```

How can i get the value from my form and put it in my ag-grid array?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Have you looked at the [forms guide](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/forms.html) on angular's website?

Comment: Yes, and I also read the [ag-grid guide](https://www.ag-grid.com/best-angular-2-data-grid/?framework=angular#gsc.tab=0), and nothing helped.
What I am trying to do is to get a value of the form from my file.ts.
On angular website, they get the value in the html, but i have to fill my ag-grid array from the file.ts...
And i really don't find any help on documentation... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's step through this [example](https://embed.plnkr.co/TJjZSWTxrRwD1BDUdINY/). Here is the initial setup:

```
//our root app component
import {Component, Directive, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [],
  providers: [],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      <label>Name</label>
      <select [(ngModel)]="name" name="Select name" class="ui fluid search selection dropdown"> 
        <option *ngFor="#n of names" [attr.value]="n">{{n}}</option>
      </select>
      <br>
      <button (click)="print()">print</button>
    </div>
  `,
  directives: []
})
export class App {
  // name: string = "Jane";
  names: string[] = ["John", "Paul", "George", "Ringo"]

  print = () => console.log(this.name)

  constructor() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      jQuery('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
    }, 1000);)
  }
}
```

> NOTE: MODEL refers to variables in the `class App`, CONTROLLER refers to functions in the `class App`, and VIEW refers to the HTML template.

The variable that is of most interest to us is `name`. Notice that it is currently commented out in the MODEL. However, I have a CONTROLLER that is able to print `this.name`. What is happening is that Angular notices that it is bound in the VIEW and so it decides to create it for us.

In the `<h2>` it is a *one-way binding*, meaning that it takes the value of what is in the MODEL. So if something were to change the value of `name` in the MODEL, Angular would update the VIEW with the new value.

In the Select there is a *two-way binding*, meaning that if the value of `name` in the VIEW gets updated, Angular will notify the MODEL that `name` is now a new value; Also, if something in the MODEL were to change `name` then the VIEW would get updated.

For example when you change the select to "Ringo", the MODEL gets updated, then the MODEL updates the VIEW so that the title reads "Hello Ringo"

Now if you uncomment `name: string = "Jane"`, then you are basically setting a default value for `name`. You might also notice that the title will then read "Hello Jane" but the select remains blank. That is because "Jane" isn't one of the options in the select.

---

**What this means for you**:

In your VIEW bind each of your inputs to variables with `[(ngModel)]` for example:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="materiel" type="number" placeholder="Numéro de matériel"   value="nMateriel"/>
```

Then in your CONTROLLER for creating a new train you will be able to use that variable as a reference:

```
createNewTrain() {
var newTrain = {
    nMateriel: this.materiel,
    nRame: 42,
    position: 'TB__BLOC_13',
    direction: 'droite',
    etat: 'mouvement',
    vitesse: '24 km/h'
};

return newTrain;
}
```

Nothing else is really needed, however I would strongly suggest to add some defaults into your TS file/MODEL for readability's sake and so that each of these variables will have a value:

```
// somewhere in your TS
materiel: number = 97
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to explain in detail, it works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by doing this in my file.ts :

(I only changed it for *nMateriel* for the example)

```
createNewTrain() {
var newTrain = {
    nMateriel: (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("nMateriel")).value,
    nRame: 42,
    position: 'TB__BLOC_13',
    direction: 'droite',
    etat: 'mouvement',
    vitesse: '24 km/h'
};

return newTrain;
}
```

Comment: Wow... from your comment and this answer, It seems that you are missing one of the best features of Angular, which is data-binding. [This video does a great job of showing Two Way-Databinding](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXjVelFtpuQ). [Here is also a plnkr that can possibly help you in understanding two way databinding](https://embed.plnkr.co/L7a5xJ/)

Comment: I watched the video and looked at the plnkr, but I know that, I use it in my application somewhere else. But as I said, in both example, they get the value with the {{value}} in the HTML code.
What i want to do is get the value in the typescript code, because I add the value to my ag-grid array from my .ts file
I feel like I'm missing something because it looks like it should be something very easy to do...